# Creating pdffrom html code

Tags: jquery, html

I can create apdf from a html file using http://www.pdfmyform.com/

I simply use the

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.pdfmyform.com/js/pdfmyform.js"></script>

<a onclick="pdfmyform(this);" href="#">PDF this page!</a>
```

And this works perfectly but im struggling to get this to work on my form (so on submit it sends the pfd to server with the contactform filled out. Can someone please assist?This is my form.

```
 <form class="well form-horizontal" data-toggle="validator" action=" " method="" id="contact_form">
<fieldset>

<!-- Form Name -->
<legend>TO BE COMPLETED BY THE INTERESTED PARTY</legend>

<!-- Text input-->

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">* Full Name:</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
  <div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
  <input data-minlength="5" id="first_name" placeholder="Full Name" class="form-control" data-error="There is a minimum of 5 characters" type="text" required>
    </div>
    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" >* Postal Address:</label> 
    <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
    <div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></span>
  <input name="Address" placeholder="Address" class="form-control" data-minlength="6"  type="text" required>
    </div>
    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">* Post Code:</label>  
    <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></span>
  <input name="zip" placeholder="Post Code" class="form-control" data-minlength="6"  type="text" required>
    </div>
    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">* Mobile (numeric):</label>  
    <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></i></span>
  <input name="phone" placeholder="07712345678" data-minlength="10" class="form-control" type="number" required>
    </div>
    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Home (numeric):</label>  
    <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></i></span>
  <input name="phone2" placeholder="07712345678" class="form-control" type="number">
    </div>

  </div>
</div>



<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">* Date of Birth: </label>  
    <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
  <input name="dob" placeholder="" class="form-control" data-minlength="6" type="date" required>
    </div>
    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
  </div>
</div>

       <div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">* E-Mail:</label>  
    <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i></span>
  <input name="email" placeholder="E-Mail Address" class="form-control"  id="email" type="email" data-error="Please enter a valid email address." required>

    </div>
       <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
  </div>
</div>
       <div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">* Confirm E-Mail:</label>  
    <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i></span>
  <input name="email" placeholder="E-Mail Address" class="form-control" data-match="#email" data-match-error="Email does not match." type="email"  required>

    </div>
       <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
  </div>
</div>
       <div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">* Profession / Company:</label>  
    <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
  <input name="company" placeholder="Company" class="form-control" data-minlength="2" type="text" required>
    </div>
    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
  </div>
</div>
       <div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label"> Notes:</label>  
    <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></i></span>
  <textarea style="height:100px" name="Notes" placeholder="Please detail all information which you feel is relevant (finance, experience, previous acquisitions, timescales, professional advice obtained, etc)" class="form-control" data-minlength="1" type="text"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">* Sign:</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
  <div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></span>
  <input data-minlength="5" id="Sign" placeholder="Print Name" class="form-control" data-error="There is a minimum of 5 characters" type="text" required>
    </div>
    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Date: </label>  
    <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
  <input name="date" placeholder="date" disabled="true" class="form-control" data-minlength="6" id="date" type="date">
    </div>
    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Success message -->
<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert" id="success_message">Success <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></i> Upon receipt of the completed form we will revert back to our client and obtain their instructions regarding discourse of information.</div>

<!-- Button -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label"></label>
  <div class="col-md-4">

  <a><button id="mainsub" class="btn btn-warning"> Accept Agreement <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span></button></a>
  </div>
</div>

</fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: can you please add full HTML code ? because its not work

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the website you are using does not support Fillable form PDF. You can check this in their FAQ section. http://www.pdfmyform.com/frequently-asked-questions/ .

You can use mpdf (https://mpdf.github.io/) or fpdf instead. I would recommend you to go for mpdf.